# Account association

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, merge-accounts

I have my SO account registered in Gmail. In my office I couldn't access Gmail due to proxy settings. So my question is, if I create a new account using Stack Exchange, and merge them, I asked for login and password of Gmail account or not? After merging, can I switch accounts to ask question and answer?

Comment: Why not simply add a login you are allowed to use within your office environment? Yeah, you'll have to do it outside of the office, but then you don't need the whole duplicate account merge. (i.e. Go to your profile > my logins > add more logins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple email ids to login to the same account. Go to your accout page, and you'll find tabs like

[image]

in the top-right of the user-information. Add as many logins as you like by clicking on `my-logins`.

The direct link should be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent).